# Haskell - Type incompatibility after qualified import

Tags: haskell, vector, hmatrix

I'm using hMatrix and the first lines of my code are:

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import qualified Data.Vector as V
```

The problem is that in my code the vector type is `V.Vector`, but some methods defined by hMatrix have type `Vector -> ...` and GHC does not understand when I try to use these methods, saying that they are not defined for the type `V.Vector`. How can I solve this problem?

**Update:**

From the documentation of hMatrix:

> The `Vector` type is a `Storable` vector from Roman Leshchinskiy’s vector package, so all array processing tools provided by this library are directly available.

However, some basic operators like `(++)` (which is present in `Data.Vector.Storable`) are not included in hMatrix. Is it impossible to use these from hMatrix or is there some simple way to tell the compiler that these types are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an explicit import for the `Vector` type:

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector (Vector)
```

Though, I didn't know external modules could break depending on how you import modules they depend on.

Comment: Great, it solved the problem! I just changed `Data.Vector` to `Data.Vector.Storable` from compatibility with hMatrix, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

hmatrix uses its own `Data.Packed.Vector` type and it's different from `Data.Vector`.

Either using `Data.Packed.Vector` in your code, or converting `Data.Vector` to `Data.Packed.Vector` before calling functions would work.

Comment: Thank you, that clarified the problem, I updated the question,

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can't break hmatrix just because you import another module. You just have a type mismatch as `vector` provides different types of vectors, including a `.Generic` interface that works for all of those.

You probably have something along the lines of

```
import Data.Vector
f :: Vector Int -> Vector Int
f = whatever
```

If you import `Data.Vector.Generic` you can write functions that work for all vector types, including those used by hmatrix.

```
import Data.Vector.Generic
f :: Vector Int -> Vector Int
f xs = xs ++ empty
```

should work with hmatrix vectors.

Comment: I am not a Haskell guru, but this seems a much better solution to me (and it also worked).